# IBAction for UIButton with it's own .xib file

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a reusable button all over my app and was planning to design it with it's own `.xib` file. The issue is that I can't connect an `IBAction` to the custom button in the controllers where it's used.

I created a new `.xib` file called `SampleButton.xib` and added a button. This is what the hierarchy and the view looks like:

[image]

I then created a new swift file called `SampleButton.swift` with a class called `SampleButton` that's a subclass of `UIButton` and assigned it as the File's Owner in my `SampleButton.xib` file.

The contents of `SampleButton.swift` are as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SampleButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() as? UIButton else {
            return
        }
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth,
                                 UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)

        view.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIButton
    }

    @IBAction func pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Called in here")
    }
}
```

I can then create a new button in my storyboard and set it to custom and the class to `SampleButton`. However now if I ctrl + drag from my button to my corresponding View Controller to create an `IBAction` for the button, it's not called. The one in the `SampleButton.swift` file is. Even if I delete the `IBAction` in the `SampleButton` file it's still not called.

Any help here? I want to be able to design the buttons separately and then have `IBactions` for them in the controllers where they're used.

Comment: Why not just set the target and selector on your `SampleButton` instance in whatever view controller you are using? Use the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method of `UIButton` to set it in your view controller class.

Comment: Not sure what is the point of a xib for a single view with no subviews.

Comment: @Pranay I was trying to do it all through xibs and storyboard

Comment: Choose "Button" in the left menu and change its class to `SampleButton` in the inspectors on the right. I wouldn't recommend this unless you need to customize it by code, but rather add a target from the view controller to a method: `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUp)` and your method `@objc func buttonPressed() {}` in the `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this same issue with some of my custom xib views and my initial thought was that I could set up my xib to be IBDesignable and then connect outlets from the storyboard rendering of my button in the view controller.

That didn't work.

So I setup a bit of a workaround using delegate callbacks from my custom views. I created IBOutlets for the view to the view controllers using them, then in `viewDidLoad` I'd set the delegate and handle the button tap in the view controller

```
import UIKit

// defines a callback protocol for the SampleButtonView
protocol SampleButtonViewDelegate: class {
    func sampleButtonTapped(_ button: SampleButton)
}

@IBDesignable
class SampleButton: UIView, NibLoadable {

    // create IBOutlet to button if you want to register a target/action directly
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    // set delegate if you want to handle button taps via delegate
    weak var delegate: SampleButtonViewDelegate?

    // initializers to make it so this class renders in view controllers
    // when using IBDesignable
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadFromNib(owner: self)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadFromNib(owner: self)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.sampleButtonTapped(_ button: self)
    }
}

// here's a sample ViewController using this view and the delegate callback method
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sampleButtonView: SampleButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sampleButtonView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: SampleButtonViewDelegate {
    func sampleButtonTapped(_ button: SampleButton) {
        // TODO: run logic for button tap here
    }
}
```

For completeness I'll also add this NibLoadable protocol definition here.

```
// I used this for the @IBDesignable functionality to work and actually render 
// my xib layouts in the storyboard view controller layouts using this class
import UIKit

/// Defines an interface for UIViews defined in .xib files.
public protocol NibLoadable {

    // the name of the associated nib file
    static var nibName: String { get }

    // loads the view from the nib
    func loadFromNib(owner: Any?)
}

public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {

    /// Specifies the name of the associated .xib file.
    /// Defaults to the name of the class implementing this protocol.
    /// Provide an override in your custom class if your .xib file has a different name than it's associated class.
    static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }

    /// Provides an instance of the UINib for the conforming class.
    /// Uses the bundle for the conforming class and generates the UINib using the name of the .xib file specified in the nibName property.
    static var nib: UINib {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        return UINib(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    /// Tries to instantiate the UIView class from the .xib file associated with the UIView subclass conforming to this protocol using the owner specified in the function call.
    /// The xib views frame is set to the size of the parent classes view and constraints are set to make the xib view the same size as the parent view. The loaded xib view is then added as a subview.
    /// This should be called from the UIView's initializers "init(frame: CGRect)" for instantiation in code, and "init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" for use in storyboards.
    ///
    /// - Parameter owner: The file owner. Is usually an instance of the class associated with the .xib.
    func loadFromNib(owner: Any? = nil) {
        guard let view = Self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: owner, options: nil).first as? UIView else {
            fatalError("Error loading \(Self.nibName) from nib")
        }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

You could also simply register the functions you defined in your view controller as the target/action functions for the button in the custom view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mySampleButtonView.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // handle button tap action in view controller here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create iboutlet of button in nib class.
2. add you nib view in your viewcontroller where its needed.
3. add target for the button outlet.

try following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
let myButton = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myButtonxibName", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? myButtonxibClassName
myButton.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addsubview(myButton)
}
@objc func buttonTapped() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Xib for what you're trying to do. Remove the `loadViewFromNib()` and the `pressed(_ sender: Any)` functions from your class above. Change your `setup()` method to customize your button. I see that you want to add a border to it. Do something like this:

```
func setup() {
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    // * Any other UI customization you want to do can be done here * //
}
```

In your storyboard, drag and drop a regular `UIButton` wherever you want to use it, set the class in the attributes inspector to `SampleButton`, connect your `IBOutlet` and `IBAction`s as necessary, and it should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this. Simpler way is to just set the target and action in view controllers. Something like:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
       sampleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didClickOnSampleButton))
    }
}
```